# Persisting circular dependent C# classes in mongodb

Tags: c#, grails, mongodb

In a grails application, the following structure is completely supported and persisted on mongodb (using mongodb plugin):

```
class Person {
    String name

    static hasMany = [pets: Pet]
}

class Pet {
    String name
    Person owner
}
```

The relation is traverse-able in both ways. I need to implement the exact same structure in C# (using mongodb official driver for C#). How is it possible to have both sides reachable from the other side. In C#, circular dependencies are not serializable and I could not find any alternative way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change child side to using an ObjectID ref to owner and make a custom transient getter getOwner() that fetches the owner based on the owner_id. Very easy to do in grails, should facilitate easy serialization in c#.